# Do Salesorce case IDs ever change?

Tags: case

For a given case number can the case ID change? I am trying to understand some behavior where a case ID definitely existed but when trying to add an object to the case there is an 'INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE' error. If the case were deleted I would expect a different error, so I am wondering why and when the case ID could change.

Comment: Does the user inserting the other object have access to that particular case record?

Comment: It's via the REST API. The "user" is the one who created it, but possibly it was then made inaccessible. I'll look into that, thank you.

Comment: No worries, posted an answer just because I realised I never actually said, "no, they don't change" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - record IDs never change on a record, the only way you'd see something like that is if you deleted a record and then created an exact copy, though of course other system fields (CreatedDate and friends) would be different.

Chances are the record has been created by one user, and is inaccessible to another.